# Twitter-Bootstrap navbar height too small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

The default height of navbar in Twitter-Bootstrap is too small. When height is increased, it encroaches the divs below.
How can I increase the height of the navbar that slides the entire page down? If this is possible, how to place navbar links to top / bottom of the navbar.

Comment: solved.
changed height in .navbar .nav

added padding-top and gave a value

Comment: post your results as an answer and approve it by ticking the green checkmark to give this question closure, this way it will help other users in the future.

Comment: Thanks you. I would love someone else, may be you, do it.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11008050/977939

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I don't love this solution but it works for the amount of time I have to spend on this.

```
.navbar .container { height: 2em; }
```

I had to also add some padding-top in the same selector to get things inside the navbar to vertically align nicely.

edit: I just re-read your question and saw you're having trouble with the "divs below".  In doing this you need to adjust padding on the body tag as well, e.g.

```
body { padding-top: 6em; }
```

per the [Twitter Bootstrap docs on Navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar):

> When you affix the navbar, remember to account for the hidden area
>   underneath. Add 40px or more of apdding to the <body>. Be sure to add
>   this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive
>   CSS.

Answer (score 6):

> Adding a padding like that is not enough if you're using responsive
>   bootstrap. In this case when you resize your window you'll get a gap
>   between top of the page and navbar. A proper solution looks like this:

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Source:
[Twitter Bootstrap - top nav bar blocking top content of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336194/twitter-bootstrap-top-nav-bar-blocking-top-content-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one. it works in any size of display.

```
.navbar .container { min-height: 83px; }


.navbar-fixed-top {
    position:static;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
</script>

$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
$(".nav-collapse").css('height', 'auto')
});

</script>
```

This solved a similar problem of mine, (The sub menus was not appearing because of the small parent ul height, on the first click) maybe it works for you as well.