# top nav bar blocking top content of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Twitter Bootstrap code

```html
  <div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
      <div class='container'>
        <a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </a>
        <div class='nav-collapse'>
          <ul class='nav'>
            <li class='active'>
              <a href='some_url'>My Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='some_url'>Option 1 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='some_url'>Another option</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='some_url'>Another option</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But when I am viewing the beginning of the page, the nav bar is blocking some of the content that is near the top of the page.  Any idea for how to make it push down the rest of the content lower when the top of the page is viewed so that the content isn't blocked by the nav bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site)

Comment: @user2428107 That question was posted later.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Add to your CSS:

```
body { 
    padding-top: 65px; 
}
```

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top):

> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body.

Comment: See additional answer below by @Spajus for how to code this for responsive Bootstrap

Comment: Definitely roll with the other answer with a little more succinctness with  @media (min-width: 980px) { body { padding-top: 60px; } }

Comment: While the other answers do address this more eloquently, this is the official answer as noted in the Bootstrap documentation for Fixed Navbar [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

Comment: How will that work if the user has a narrower screen or simply resizes the window? The topmost contents will be blocked again by the expanded nav bar section.

Answer (score 386):

Adding a padding like that is not enough if you're using responsive bootstrap. In this case when you resize your window you'll get a gap between top of the page and navbar. A proper solution looks like this:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This should really be integrated into bootstrap somehow. You should fork and submit a pull request.

Comment: Good solution, but there is still something not solved. Take a look to this question I have just made and see if anyone can give a hand on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763707/space-behind-bootstrap-navbar

Comment: Even more succinctly: @media (min-width: 981px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
}

Comment: @Ted for me it has to be min-width: 980px ;-)

Comment: @white_gecko lol. Yep. That 980 wanted to be just a little extra special unique ;-)

Comment: I had an issue in IE8 using Ted's solution. After altering to Spajus's solution it works better in IE8. This has to do with the @media type not working in IE8.

Comment: It's always fun to add this to the minified CSS file. :)

Comment: Only `<style>body {padding-top: 60px;}</style>` is needed, assuming you place that code before including the stylesheet for responsive design. Example (see source code) http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html - PS. As you may have guessed, that declaration inside the media query is already present in the responsive stylesheet.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but where exactly do you put this? in the css file? do you replace the existing body tag?

Comment: @brittohalloran If I remember rightly they are doing similar behaviour to this in the upcoming Bootstrap4

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't this solution again introduce the content blocking problem in devices with screen size less than 979px? Because that's exactly what I see when I resize my browser window...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I am wondering that this needs to be added. I was sure bootstrap will create a padding by its own with all it's containers following each other....

Answer (score 151):

For bootstrap 3, the class `navbar-static-top` instead of `navbar-fixed-top` prevents this issue, unless you need the navbar to always be visible.

Comment: This works however might leave some space above the navbar. You may need to modify site.css and remove padding-top 80px from body.

Comment: I tried everything and this is the only answer that worked. Because this is the most general solution and doesn't depend on screen size, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Why does this work instead of navbar-fixed-top?

Comment: It did not worked for  bootstap 3.3.4. I see fixed nav example at bootstrap site http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/, It uses padding-top

Comment: What ZZZ said about getting rid of the white space that appears above the navbar did not work for me. Does anyone know how to get rid of the white space that appears above the navbar when switching from navbar-fixed-top to navbar-static-top ?

Comment: while this works, it makes the navbar static and not fixed. that means that when you scroll down the navbar will disappear... at least for me that's not good.

Comment: I want the navbar to always be visible, how can I have a fixed nav-bar without it blocking the top content? I'm using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 64):

a much more handy solution for your reference, it works perfect in all of my projects:

change your first 'div' from

```
<div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
```

to

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
```

Comment: The static navbar disappears when scrolling.

Comment: Re: @DanielC.Sobral response - you could switch it out for the fixed one in js if it scrolls off the top

Answer (score 17):

I am using jQuery to solve this problem. This is the snippet for BS 3.0.0:

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
    $('body').css('padding-top', parseInt($('#main-navbar').css("height"))+10);
});

$(window).load(function () { 
    $('body').css('padding-top', parseInt($('#main-navbar').css("height"))+10);        
});
```

Comment: I was using a image over the navbar and having real problems with the content being hidden.  This worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. this answer worked like a charm for me :)
I'd like to add one thing. When you load the page, the body is set to the top before it adjusts itself automatically because jquery doesnt run instantly. To make it smoother, I added this in CSS
body{
   padding-top: //initial height of my navbar;
}
This helps in smooth transition! Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks for inspiring a programatic solution! I have a great working implementation now in GWT with nice encapsulated well structured code... thanks to a lack of Javascript ;-)

Answer (score 9):

In my project derived from the [MVC 5 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) I found that changing the body padding had no effect. The following worked for me:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    body {
        margin-top:100px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    body {
        margin-top:50px;
    }
}
```

It resolves the cases where the navbar folds into 2 or 3 lines. This can be inserted into bootstrap.css anywhere after the lines
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

Comment: After studying all answers, this seems like the best solution. (navbar-static-top makes it disappear when scrolling, & the dummy navbar doesn't take into account how the real navbar menu might wrap.) I found that bootstrap has four hardcoded width cases: <768 pixels, 768-991, 992-1199, and >1199. See how your menu behaves for those 4 cases. For non-admin users of my website, I only needed the 100 pixels for the 768-991 case & that was sufficient. Was put into site.css. Or, I noticed that our menu is wider for admin users and wraps more easily. So we put conditional style code in _Layout.cshtml

Comment: using margin-top instead of padding-top moves down a content beneath of navbar. It's true that padding-top applied to body doesn't work in MVC but it seems it works when applied to a body container.

Answer (score 9):

I've had good success with creating a dummy non-fixed nav bar right before my real fixed nav bar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav> <!-- Dummy nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> <!-- Real nav bar -->
    <!-- Nav bar details -->
</nav>
```

The spacing works out great on all screen sizes.

Comment: I thought this was the answer at first and was all set to give an upvote. But then I realized it doesn't work when the size gets narrow enough to have it stack the menu buttons. :-(

Comment: You're right it won't work with menu stacking without additional code. I usually just keep my menu bars at one line of height and turn the menu options into a hamburger button when the size narrows.

Comment: i have no idea why, but this works. can u elaborate on why it works ?

Comment: Great idea! as it's useful when some pages have a navbar and some not, as it's not possible to differentiate froms css file.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. It works on all devices, even when the navbar breaks into two lines. +1

Comment: Doesn't work. the content at the top of the body still continues to be covered by the navigation bar if the bar height increases due to additional role-based items on iPad. I am trying to avoid adding <div class="top-buffer"></div>

Answer (score 9):

The bootstrap v4 [starter template css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css) uses:

```
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As seen on [this example](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) from Twitter, add this before the line that includes the responsive styles declarations:

```html5
<style> 
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
</style>
```

Like so:

```html5
<link href="Z/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }
</style>
<link href="Z/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 4):

using `percentage` is much better solution than `pixels`.

```
body {
  padding-top: 10%; //This works regardless of display size.
}
```

If needed you can still be explicit by adding different `breakpoints` as mentioned in another answer by `@spajus`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This solution is not viable for newer versions of Bootstrap, where the navbar-inverse and navbar-static-top classes are not available.

Using MVC 5, the way I fixed mine, was to simply add my own Site.css, loaded after the others, with the following line:
`body{padding: 0}`

and I changed the code in the beginning of _Layout.cshtml, to be:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                <div class="top-navbar">
```

Comment: `navbar-static-top` is not defined in Bootstrap4.  Neither is `navbar-inverse`

Comment: I guess this answer is out-dated, then. I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

with **navbar navbar-default** everything works fine, but if you are using **navbar-fixed-top** you have to include custom style body { padding-top: 60px;} otherwise it will block content underneath.

Comment: This doesn't add any information that isn't already in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems will happen here:

1. Page load (content hidden)
2. Internal links like this will scroll to the top, and be hidden by the navbar:

> ```
> <nav>...</nav>              <!-- 70 pixels tall -->
> <a href="#hello">hello</a>  <!-- click to scroll down -->
> <hr style="margin: 100px">
> <h1 id="hello">World</h1>   <!-- Help!  I'm 70 pixels hidden! -->
> ```

## Bootstrap 4 w/ internal page links

To fix 1), as Martijn Burger said above, the bootstrap v4 starter template css uses:

```
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}
```

To fix 2) check out [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768).  This code mostly works (but not on 2nd click of same hash):

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() { scrollBy(0, -70) })
```

This code animates A links with jQuery (not slim jQuery):

```
  // inline theme global code here
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var body = $('html,body'), NAVBAR_HEIGHT = 70;
    function smoothScrollingTo(target) {
      if($(target)) body.animate({scrollTop:$(target).offset().top - NAVBAR_HEIGHT}, 500);
    }
    $('a[href*=\\#]').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      smoothScrollingTo(this.hash);
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      smoothScrollingTo(location.hash);
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found so far, that does not involve hard coding heights and breakpoints is to add an extra `<nav...` tag to the markup.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" aria-hidden="true">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
```

By doing it this way the `@media` breakpoints are identical, the height is identical (provided your `navbar-brand` is the tallest object in the `navbar` but you can easily substitute another element in the non `fixed-top` navbar.

Where this fails is with screen readers which will now present 2 `navbar-brand` elements.  This points at the need for a `not-for-sr` class to prevent that element from showing up for screen readers.  However that class does not exist  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/screenreaders/

I've tried to compensate for the screen reader issue with `aria-hidden="true"` but  https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/sensible-aria-usage/hidden/ seems to indicate this will probably not work when the screen reader is in focus mode which is of course the only time you actually need it to work...

Answer (score 1):

you should add

```css
#page {
  padding-top: 65px
}
```

to not destroy a sticky footer or something else

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='navbar' data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
```

If your navbar is on the top of the page originally, set the value to 0. Otherwise, set the value for `data-offset-top`to the value of the content above your navbar.

Meanwhile, you need to modify the `css` as such:

```
.affix{
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("body").css({
    'padding-top': $(".navbar").outerHeight() + 'px'
  })
});
```

Comment: This will not work if the window is resized since your padding-top is only applied at document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.stick-top` which would do the same job of fixing the navbar to the top when scrolled without having to add any css padding

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-white navbar-light sticky-top pt-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="/images/logo-full.png" alt="logo" width="150">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
     .....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can set margin based on screen resolution

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
body {
    margin-top:100px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  body {
    margin-top:50px;
  }
}

body{
  padding-top: 10%;
}

#nav{
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #8b0000;
   width: 100%;
   top:0;
}
```