# Twitter Bootstrap Fixed navbar Overlaps texxt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I can't seem to get my fixed navbar from twitter bootstrap to stop overlapping my text.

I looked at [twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site) for my problem.

and it seems like this code will work best for my problem:

```
body { padding-top: 40px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}
```

But, I don't think I'm correctly implementing it. I pasted it over the original body in bootstrap.css but nothing has changed.

How would I correctly implement the code?

Comment: specify your question what you have tried? where is your code ? what you  want to do ?

Comment: I pasted the code over the original "body" code in bootstrap.css, which doesn't contain anything. I'm trying to implement the code I pasted correctly. 

The code is the css that came with  bootstrap.  @ http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: body {padding-top : 60px;} try this

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out! I had to make a custom.css file rather than just putting the code into their given css file, and then include the custome.css in my html.