# Scroll bar overlapping fixed DIV - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this bootstrap template for my new project ( http://www.bootply.com/render/96266 )
I am much satisfied with the design metrics, the only small problem I am facing is that the navbar which is static-top is overlapping the scrollbar.

I tried changing navbar to fixed-top but still it overlaps the scrollbar.After lots of troubleshooting, I found out that .column class has overflow:auto and that is causing the problem.
When I decided to use overflow:hidden / scroll / inherit but the result was not what I expected.

Can someone help with this?

```
JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YHRwA/2/
```

Comment: Please try to reproduce this problem with a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Lowkase: Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YHRwA/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right in the docs:

> When you affix the navbar, remember to account for the hidden area
>   underneath. Add 40px or more of padding to the . Be sure to add
>   this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive
>   CSS

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124805/3222041)

Comment: I tired your suggestion it didnt help, would love if you could check out the fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/YHRwA/2/

Answer (score 0):

does your element have a `z-index` applied?
This allows the rendered elements to be arranged with a 'depth' of display [what goes above what]

Answer (score 0):

They have one main div which is positioned in way that it will span the whole height & width of the browser view-port `(top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0}` & all content is then positioned inside that div. The name is `.box`.

Then there is another container, the class applied to that div is `.column` & it has overflow set to auto. So the scroll bar is not actually of the browser but of this div & All of them are set height to 100%, this will take up the viewport height & width.

Now browser default scroll bar width changes browser to browser. So I guess you've to entirely redo the HTML.

To resolve it fast you can remove the `bottom:0` of the box.

Comment: Hi Suraj, thanks for that reply, i think redoing the entire HTML is solution as the fast resolution also doesnt work .

Comment: Ok. Do they have any support? They must have done with some purpose. This logic may have something to do with the mobile device output.