# Fixed nav-bar in twitter boostrap causing top content of a section hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i click on particular link on navbar it slide down to that section of the page. But since i am using fixed navbar it hides some of the content of that section.

**Ex:** When i click on **About** on navigation menu the page slide to that section. For below example About Me is overlapped navbar.

```
About Me (This part is Hidden below navigation menu)
Some Random Text Here
Some More
And More....
```

What i want to do is that when i click on a link it should slide just enough so that every thing on that section is visible.(It means that the page should slide up till the bottom of the navigaton bar)

```
<body>
    <div class="nav navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="pull-left">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parallax-overlay"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <img class="img-circle" src="img/profile.jpg" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">
        <h1>Nakib Momin</h1>
        <p>Student Blogger And Software Developer</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="">Learn More</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

#CSS

```
body, html{height: 100%}

.nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}


.parallax-overlay {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 120;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(img/pattern.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: rgba(44,62,80,0.4);
z-index: 2;
}

.jumbotron {

  background-image:url('main.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:120px;
}

.jumbotron h1, .jumbotron p, .jumbotron a, .jumbotron button, .jumbotron img
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.jumbotron img
{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.jumbotron button
{
  margin-top: 18px; 
  width: 130px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #e3e3e3;

}

.jumbotron a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into issues before with fixed navbars overlapping content, and the solution was to add padding to the <strike>fixed navbar</strike> body.  Check out this answer: [twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site).

**EDIT:** I [made a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf2g8/2/) that replicates the problem - it looks like adding a padding-top to the body fixes the problem of the fixed navbar overlapping the body where content is rendered:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
}
```

Comment: any other way....i tried this thing earlier but it doesn't seems to work the way i intended.

Comment: You'd ought to post your code in the question - I'm not sure what the issue is if your fixed navbars have bottom padding without looking at it.

Comment: I have added both css and html