# laravel 4 jquery script is not loaded in all pages

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I am including jquery and bootstrap in a Laravel project.

I have organized the folders as follows:

- app/views/

Inside views, there is the file *home.blade.php* and there are two folders: *layout* and *account*.

- app/views/layout
- app/views/account

Inside *layout*, there is the *main.blade.php* where i have the entire HTML code. This is where i specify the location of both bootstrap files and jQuery files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Authentication system</title>
        {{ HTML::style('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
        {{ HTML::style('/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}
    </head>
    <body>
        @if(Session::has('global'))
            <p>{{Session::get('global')}}</p><!--It can be a div, span, etc-->
        @endif
        @include('layout.navigation')
        <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
        <p style="color: red;">End of everything</p>
        </div><!--Fin del div class container-->
        <!-- Javascript Files required for page-->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--Referencias:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site-->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document.body).css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height() + 25);
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    $(document.body).css('padding-top', $('#topnavbar').height() + 25);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The files *views/layout/navigation.blade.php* and *views/home.blade.php* (which is the default page) look fine because i see through firebug that everything is fine. views/home.blade.php looks like this:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
    <p>Inside the default page.</p>
    @if(Auth::check())
        <p>Hello {{Auth::user()->username}}, you are now signed in!!!</p>
    @else
        <p>(Not signed in yet)</p>
    @endif
@stop
```

Nevertheless, when each of the rest of the views inside the app/views/account/ folder (one level below compared to the previous script), for example, app/views/account/forgot.blade.php,

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')
    <form action="{{URL::route('account-forgot-password-post')}}" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            Email: <input type="email" name="email"{{ (Input::old('email')) ? ' value="'.e(Input::old('email')).'"' : ''}}>
            @if($errors->has('email'))
                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
            @endif
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Recover">
        {{ Form::token()}}
    </form>
@stop
```

in firebug i see there is this error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

Which is telling me that for those pages inside app/views/account/ (one level deeper), jQuery is not being loaded. I am stuck here. What is going wrong? I am confused, since the rest of the elements of each page are being loaded or read properly. For example, i added the following message just before (or just above) the script tags (where i call the jQuery files):

```
<p style="color: red;">End of everything</p>
```

In all the pages I see that message.
So why aren't jQuery scripts loaded? How can i fix this?

Comment: Where you place your JS files?

Comment: try to load them like this {{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'); }}