# Same CSS spacing rendering differently for two containers only in mobile version

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Context:

I'm trying to simulate a "jumbotron" but not really, because instead of one big image, I need two images splitting the size of the jumbotron. The code I have below works well on screen sizes "sm" and up in Bootstrap lingo.

For screen size "xs", instead of splitting the jumbotron, I want to now stack it. Herein lies the problem, because somehow the space created by the CSS `jumbotron-home-gap` renders differently for the first image and the second image.

Please help thanks!

View:

```
<%= render "layouts/jumbotronhome", obj: "snowsports" %>
<%= render "layouts/jumbotronhome", obj: "outdoors" %>
```

Partial:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 jumbotron cta" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path "#{obj}.jpg" %>)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row jumbotron-home-gap">
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg cta-button" id="cta-button" href="/<%= obj %>" role="button">Rent <%= obj %> gear</a></p>
    </div>
    <a name="how-to"></a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
  .jumbotron-home-gap {
    padding-top: 40%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){
  .jumbotron-home-gap {
    padding-top: 70%;
  }
}
```

Photos:

320 px screen: [image]

768 px screen: [image]

HTML generated:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 jumbotron cta" style="background-image: url(/assets/snowsports.jpg)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row jumbotron-home-gap">
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg cta-button" id="cta-button" href="/snowsports" role="button">Rent snowsports gear</a></p>
    </div>
    <a name="how-to"></a>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 jumbotron cta" style="background-image: url(/assets/outdoors.jpg)">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row jumbotron-home-gap">
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg cta-button" id="cta-button" href="/outdoors" role="button">Rent outdoors gear</a></p>
    </div>
    <a name="how-to"></a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add html generated

Comment: Done, added at very bottom @skv

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to "see" the issue, may be a live URL or a jsfiddle?  I am seeing that both the jumbotron-home-gap share the same padding-top

Comment: Exactly.. that's why I'm so confused

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was happening. Bootstrap's fixed navbars overlap content, therefore a padding is required. This was always a problem, but only in the mobile stacked version was it noticeable. Fixed by adding:

```
body { padding-top: 50px; /* default navbar size */ }
```

Credit to this answer: [twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site)