# Bootstrap not acting from master page file

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, master-pages

I have a master page that has a header bar in the page that is using the bootstrap.

**Here is the code**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <div class="left">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_home" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/HeadHome.png" CssClass="headIcons" />
                </div>
                <div class="left">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_config" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/HeadConfig.png" CssClass="headIcons" />
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_profile" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/HeadProfile.png" CssClass="headIcons" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is my Webform ASPX code

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"">
            <div class="b-orange" style="background-color: #f29123; height: 5px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="top: 60px;">
        <img src="../Images/bSimplex_Header_Logo.jpg" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is that the page adds the header but doesn't recognise the height so when i add things into the page it goes from the top and not from the header**

Some images:

[image]

As you can the first row in my ASPX page is starting from the very top and not from the navbar in the master page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site)

Comment: @Nathan The problem with setting the pixel like shown in the answer is that when the screen size gets smaller the bar gets larger. (More than 70px)

Comment: Read the other answers, they accommodate for that.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `navbar-fixed-top` makes the navbar sticky by `position: fixed;`.

To have page content always be below the navbar, add body padding:

`body { padding-top: 50px; }`

Or even better using less:

`body { padding-top: @navbar-height; }`

See [Bootstrap documentation on fixed-to-top navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)