# Bootstrap 3 and nav bars that snap or pin as you scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 here and here's my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/5/). I really like my header navbar, but would like to tweak it so that it 'snaps' or 'pins' to the top of the page as the user views, *almost* exactly like they do it on [Rancher](http://rancher.com). With the only difference being, they transition from a transparent background to a black one, and I just want to stick with a solid gray background at all times.

Looking at that page source, I can't quite lock in on where the trick is because most of their JS is pretty heavily minified. Any ideas as to how I could achieve this?

Maybe some JS magic like so (?):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fixIT = $(this).scrollTop() >= navPos;
    var setPos = fixIT ? 'fixed' : 'relative' ;
    var logoSH = fixIT ? 'show' : 'hide' ;

    $('#nav').css({position: setPos});
    $('#mini-logo')[logoSH](300);
});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have the transition in the background of your navbar then there is **no need** to add js in your code. You can do it simple with media query event and css.

On the snippet above I wrap all your navbar with a class "checkmate" and added a media query for the "view" when window is on 640px or less.

```css
.acLogo {
    background-image : url("http://placehold.it/120x50");
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading, .form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.account-wall {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.login-title {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}
.profile-img {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.need-help {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.new-account {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
img.user-summary {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
div.user-summary {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
div.user-summary > img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
div.user-name {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    font-style: italic;
    display: block;
}
div.user-status {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.checkmate {
    position:fixed!important;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index: 99;
}

.the_content {
    position: relative;
    top:130px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {

    .the_content {
        position: relative;
        top:400px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {

    .checkmate {
        position: relative!important;
    }
    .the_content {
        position: relative;
        top:0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="title" content="My App" />
    <link href="css/style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ=="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="checkmate">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default checkmate">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand acLogo" href="/"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/features"><b>FEATURES</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/compare"><b>COMPARE US</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/pricing"><b>FIZZBUZZ</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/company"><b>FOOBAR</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/docs"><b>DOCS</b></a></li>
                </ul><form action="/app/dashboard/search" method="POST">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/app/dashboard">
                                <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Sign up" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/app/dashboard">
                                <input class="btn btn-link" type="button" value="Sign in" /></a></li>
                    </ul></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="the_content">
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
    lel<br>
    lol<br>
    lall<br>
    lesdl<br>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.orgSelector').dropdown();
    $('.orgSelector').tooltip();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need for all that extra markup, CSS classes and media query, _boostrap_ has it already built-in, to just add to existing markup.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options, no extra html markup or CSS needed:

1. Add scroll event handler.

   With this you add/remove the class `navbar-fixed-top`. What does make this work is, when someone scroll the page the `navbar` position changes to `position: fixed` which make it stay at its position.
2. Add `navbar-fixed-top` to the `nav` element's class.

   This way, and if no extra styling is needed during scroll, no need to catch the scroll at all.

Also, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site) and bootstrap docs, you might need an extra padding on the body (or the element next after the `navbar`) to make up for the `navbar`'s height when in `position: fixed`, or it could hide some of the page content. If this cause you issue, let me know and I assist you in how to fix it.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("#navbar").addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
      $("#navbar").removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }

});
```

An update of your [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/oh69hq71/10/)

If you want to add additional styling while it's at its `position: fixed`, just add this to your custom CSS

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

Another update of your [fiddle with added CSS rule](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/oh69hq71/11/)

If you want to do something else at some other scroll position, you just update your event handler like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var el = $("#navbar");
    if (st > 0) {
      el.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      if (st > 50) {
        el.addClass('navbar-custom');
      } else {
        el.removeClass('navbar-custom');
      }
    } else {
      el.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom');
    }        
});
```

Yet another update of your [fiddle with added a second CSS rule](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/oh69hq71/12/)

Answer (score 1):

I have check your code.

You have to do minor changes with `nav` .

Here is updated code : https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/9/

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    $('.orgSelector').dropdown();
   $('.orgSelector').tooltip();
  
    var nav = $('.nav-container');
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 136) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        }
    });
 
});
```

```css
.acLogo {
 background-image : url("http://placehold.it/120x50");
        background-size: 100%;
 height: 50px;
        width: 120px;
    padding-top: 15px;        
}
.form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading, .form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.account-wall {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.login-title {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}
.profile-img {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.need-help {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.new-account {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
img.user-summary {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div.user-summary {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
div.user-summary > img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
div.user-name {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
}
div.user-status {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.f-nav{ z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand acLogo" href="/"></a>
           </div>
           <div>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/features"><b>FEATURES</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/compare"><b>COMPARE US</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/pricing"><b>FIZZBUZZ</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/company"><b>FOOBAR</b></a></li>
               <li><a href="/docs"><b>DOCS</b></a></li>
             </ul><form action="/app/dashboard/search" method="POST">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/app/dashboard">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Sign up" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="/app/dashboard">
<input class="btn btn-link" type="button" value="Sign in" /></a></li>
                  </ul></form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </nav>
```

Comment: There is no need for that extra CSS class, _boostrap_ has it already built-in, and as you already added the `navbar-fixed-top` class to the `nav` element, your script doesn't do anything more than just add/remove the unnecessary extra class.