# About Bootstrap 4 - Navbar top placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4.
I have a question about the Navbar "Fixed top" class. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#placement
The Navbar "Fixed top" class covers content.

like this demo below, the Navbar covers `<div class="jumbotron">`,I want the Navbar to not cover it, what should I do?

I have no idea how to prevent the Navbar from covering content, because the device's size is visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
    <hr class="m-y-2">
    <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
    <p class="lead">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can make your content start under the fixed navbar.

Comment: That's how fixed works ...

Comment: Could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 27):

Try using `sticky-top` instead of `fixed-top` this worked for me on Bootstrap 4 Alpha6.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way would be to set an enclosing  tag to the rest of the content that it is covering and set the **margin-top** attribute in **css** in *vw* or *vh* or *percentages* (Depending on your use case) to make sure no content is hidden by the fixed bar on the top. This will make sure it is even resizable without significant changes in the navbar's effect on the page although i would suggest changing the margin on the basis of page size using the **@media** controller in **css**.

For more information on your problem you can check this thread:
[twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with css

```
<style>
  body {
     margin-top: 50px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h) on w3schools.com

The 4.0.0 version of bootstrap css doesn't work properly. I had the same problem and replacing with 3.3.7 version fixed it.

Comment: Warning: Many things could break going from 4 to 3

Answer (score 0):

You can Use class .sticky-top or overcome this using custom CSS

```
body{
    padding-top: 70px;    
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you pad the top doesn't the scroll get goofed up too?