# Navbar panel overlaps text

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am making a forum and faced with the problem that the top navigation bar overlaps the text on all pages of the site. Am I missing something?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Forum</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand navLogo" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"></a>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
//Panel code
      </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
 <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats because your navigation bar is using fixed position or absolute. Try using relative instead of absolute. Or, you can give margin top to main container after nav bar

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane yes, its work, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [twitter bootstrap navbar fixed top overlapping site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site)