# Bootstrap 5 push column down according to navbar height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do I push down the left-most column a `position-fixed` according to navbar height which has `fixed-top`???

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%!important;
        }
        .navbar-brand img {
            filter: invert(65%) sepia(91%) saturate(7314%) hue-rotate(210deg) brightness(101%) contrast(98%);
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        .scrollable {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%!important; /* Otherwise we have to use h-100 on the .scrollable section?!? */
        }

        .scrollable:hover {
            overflow: auto;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 3px;
            height: 3px;
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: #FEFEFE;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #6c757d;
        }
    </style>

    <title>BS5 Layout</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-light">

    <header class="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top p-0 border-bottom">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <a class="navbar-brand text-primary px-2" href="#">
                <img src="https://simplisti.com/assets/logo.svg" width="32" height="32" class="d-inline-block align-top " loading="lazy">
                Brand
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10 border-start" aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb mt-3 px-2">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">List</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <section class="h-100 col-md-3 col-lg-2 position-fixed p-0 scrollable">
                This won't scroll all the way to bottom?!?
                item<br>
                ...
                Last item
            </section>
            <section class="h-100 col-md-5 col-lg-7 offset-md-3 offset-lg-2 p-0 border-start">
                Repeat this content and navbar disappears after X number of scrolls<br>
                ...
                Last line<br>
            </section>
            <section class="h-100 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-0 border-start">
                SIDE
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

**Body padding is required as your nav is fixed!** From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site/11124805#11124805) quoting an older version of the docs:

> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content unless you add
> padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our
> snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Include this line after the bootstrap stuff! [Working demo](https://codepen.io/ni_l/full/RwGgJQV) and [code](https://codepen.io/ni_l/pen/RwGgJQV?editors=1100)!

Comment: I've tried this...but what happens if the navbar changes height, like font-size increase? Also even when hardcoded, the left-column list will not scroll to the bottom...I can't see the `'Last line`???

Comment: The best solution seems to duplicate the navbar at the top of each column...that pushes the content down and doesn't cause the left-column from not showing the last line item...of course this feels gross but it works?!? Short of using JS to calculate the height - but that causes issues like I said in previous comment?

Comment: You are right, if the nav's height changes, we'll need to change the body padding as well.

Comment: So far, I've stuck two phantom DIV's are the top of each column. I set the height of each to 57px which works perfectly until something changes in the navbar. I could use some JS to get the height and set those DIV's height's on the fly...seems kinda hackish. I was hoping for a CSS specific solution. :o might just hack it at this point...seems futile

Comment: @Alex.Barylski Did you find the css solution for this?