# BOOTSTRAP NAVBAR AND CAROUSEL

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-4, carousel, navbar, boost-ref

I have a problem when using Boostrap's navbar and carousel since in PC view it hides the image behind the navbar and when you put mobile view it hides the carousel images even more. some help?
Thanks for the support!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJPUz.jpg)

Comment: When using a fixed navbar you must add a spacer to the top of the page to push content down.  See this similar SO question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124805/943435

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.