# Space behind bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

Using bootstrap's `navbar`, I am trying to figure out how to make it not to hide the top of the body section.

Actually, it is very well solved using what is recommended here:

[Twitter Bootstrap - top nav bar blocking top content of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336194/twitter-bootstrap-top-nav-bar-blocking-top-content-of-the-page)

But there is still something that is not working: when you have a link like this:

```
<li><a href="#section1">Go to Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section2">Go to Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section3">Go to Section 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#section4">Go to Section 4</a></li>
```

And

```
<h4 id="Section 1">Section 1</h4>
<p>Content of Section 1</p>
<p><a href="#">Back to Top</a></p>

<h4 id="Section 2">Section 2</h4>
<p>Content of Section 2</p>
<p><a href="#">Back to Top</a></p>

<h4 id="Section 3">Section 3</h4>
<p>Content of Section 3</p>
<p><a href="#">Back to Top</a></p>

<h4 id="Section 4">Section 4</h4>
<p>Content of Section 4</p>
<p><a href="#">Back to Top</a></p>
```

In this case, when you click on, for example, Section 2 direct link (or shortcut), the page properly scrolls-down until the section 2, but it hides the beginning of it behind the bootstrap navbar.

Any clue about how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the :target psuedo-selector to a linked CSS you can apply a defined padding to your selected link (as long as it displays in your browser as: www.example.com#link1).

I spent the last 2 hours trying to search the web trying to find Jquery or JS to apply padding to the target div and after modifying my Google [search terms found this](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/)

There might be a way to fool proof this with older browsers, but for the time being, this makes me a happy camper.

Comment: I am using this `:target` technique, though I just want to say that it automatically pushes my content down (by the amount of padding) when I access any anchor. The space is restored when I click a different anchor in the same document. Has anyone else noticed this and are you aware of any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Put some top padding on your `<h4>`'s to account for your `navbar`'s height. I.e. put this in your CSS:

```
h4 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Of course, change `30px` to you actual `navbar` height.

Comment: It's a solution and for now is all what I have, so may be I'll leave it as you said. But obviously it makes my page to have huge ugly spaces between each section.

Comment: Hi, just try and put a <div id="dummy></div>, and css #dummy { padding-top: 30px;}. It is not very lean, but at least you won't have it repeated

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and haven't found a real solution, but just more workarounds (like the "padding-top" work-around itself, that seems very hackish to me). It looks like the topbar issue is still unsolved, people just hack around it somehow.

One non-invasive work-around that works for me (as good as it can) is to add the following JavaScript to the page (apart from the "padding-top" hack):

```javascript
var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -50) };
if (location.hash) shiftWindow();
window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
```

I found this in a [comment to a bootstrap GitHub issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768#issuecomment-6531466). However, the function isn't executed in all necessary occasions (e.g. when going to the same anchor again).

A more reliable work-around is moving the anchor positions using CSS relative positioning (found in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/4271479):

```
a.anchor{display: block; position: relative; top: -250px; visibility: hidden;}
```

However, this is more invasive because you have to give your anchors a class (to distinguish it from links). So you have to update all your anchor HTML code (which might not always be possible, e.g. when you are dealing with a rigid CMS that generates your anchors):

```
<a class="anchor" id="top"></a>
```