# Bootstrap - navbar-fixed-top covers content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fixed, navbar

I have a question about navbar-fixed-top. Well, I have a simple problem with it. My fixed navbar covers content, for example in "About us" page, it covers row with "About us" title.

I have no idea how can I fix it, because when I resize website (mobile devices size) the header is visible.

Of course I have this kind of problem with headers in other pages (Full Width and 404).

Also, in Index page, it covers some of carousel slider.

Information:

- website: http://testerix.site90.com/index.html
- bootstrap 2.3.2

Let me know, how can I fix it on all resolutions.

Comment: there are several copies of this issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124777/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top-overlapping-site 
says add this css:
body { padding-top: 40px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}
____________________________________________________________________
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336194/twitter-bootstrap-top-nav-bar-blocking-top-content-of-the-page
this worked for me:
For bootstrap 3, navbar-static-top instead of fixed prevents this issue, unless you need the navbar to always be visible

Answer (score 22):

the response is in the page:

> [Twitter Bootstrap - top nav bar blocking top content of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336194/twitter-bootstrap-top-nav-bar-blocking-top-content-of-the-page?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Add to your CSS:

```
body { 
    padding-top: 65px; 
}
```

or a more complex solution but responsive, if your navbar change the height( ex in tablets appears in more to 60px; or is different ) use a mixed solution with css and javascript

CSS:

```
    #godown{
   height: 60px;
}
```

HTML (resumen)

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" id="navMenu">
...

</nav>

<!-- This div make the magic :) -->

<div class="godown-60" id="godown"></div>

<!-- the rest of your site -->
...
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
//insert this in your jquery
//control the resizing of menu and go down the content in the correct position

    $("#navMenu").resize(function () {
        $('#godown').height($("#navMenu").height() + 10);
    });

    if ($("#navMenu").height() > $('#godown').height()) $('#godown').height($("#navMenu").height() + 10);

</script>
```

Comment: Worked for me, but feels so hacky.

Answer (score 11):

Try class="navbar-static-top". It still allows navigation bar to be stay on the top but doesn't block content.

Comment: Yes but it stops the sticky effect so when you scroll down you lose the navbar.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but yes, you can expect to lose the persistent "sticky" navbar feature.

Answer (score 8):

`position: sticky` instead of `position: static` did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks it worked! In my case, `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-secondary navbar-dark sticky-top justify-content-center">  `

Answer (score 1):

```
var navHeight = $("#menu").height();
$("body").css({paddingTop: (navHeight+12)+'px'});
```

Try this easy way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
// add appropriate media query if required to target mobile nav only
.nav { overflow-y: hidden !important }
```

This should make sure the nav block doesn't stretch downpage and covers the page content.

Comment: Really not a fix. Nav blocks DO change. You dont want to stop that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id or class to the content, and then give it a margin top enough to make the content show without the static navbar hindering it  and add the "!important" attribute to make it work.....

Answer (score 0):

It's possible setting a variable for the paddingTop of the body to the height of the navbar could also work and is subsequently a bit more responsive than a fixed 60/65px value.

```
let padding = $("nav").height() + "px";
```

A practical example is the Bootstrap .navbar-toogler button and adding a click event to it and setTimeout function which allows the height to change then apply the new value as paddingTop to the body.

jQuery:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                let padding = $("nav").height() + "px";
                $("body").css("paddingTop", padding)
            }, 500)
        })
```

vanillaJS:

```
document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler").onclick = function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                let padding = document.querySelector("nav").offsetHeight + "px";
                document.body.style.paddingTop=padding;
            }, 500)
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. It will retain the fixed property of navbar

```css
.navbar{
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
}
```