# Bootstrap top navbar blocking my content laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have a problem regarding about the navbar. Just now when I was able to do make the navbar stick to the top when scrolling, the top content was then blocking my view and I actually used this question to help me but it didn't work, is there another solution or am I just putting it at the wrong place? Here is the question that I used to help me, [Twitter Bootstrap - top nav bar blocking top content of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336194/twitter-bootstrap-top-nav-bar-blocking-top-content-of-the-page)

I tried using this following of the codes but it doesn't help:

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

This is what happen
[image]

So here is the codes:

app.blade.php(where my navbar is)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

   <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: blue">
                <div class="navbar-header" style="padding-left: 50px">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @include('layouts.testSidebar')

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}" style="color: white">
                        @yield('title')
                    </a>
                </div>



                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>


                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color:blue">
                                    <b style="color: white">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: blue">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="background-color: blue">
                                            <b style="color: white">Logout</b>
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

test.css (this is inside my sidebar code, I don't think the sidebar code is needed so I just put the css since it affect the navbar also)

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    padding-top: 65px; 
    }
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}



#sidebar{
    background:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    left:-200px;
    top:0px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible{
    left:0px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}

ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

ul li a{
    background:#0000FF;
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #111;
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar-btn{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:20px;
    height:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:-60px;
}

#sidebar-btn span{
    height:1px;
    background:white;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:block;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2){
    width:75%;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3){
    width:50%;
}

#navbar-toggle collapsed{
    background:#0000FF;
}

.navbar {
    background:#0000FF;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}


nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, 
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#test .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 180px;
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the bootstrap docs regarding the fixed navbar, when they say: _Make sure to include this __after__ the core Bootstrap CSS._? (Emphasis is in the docs) Are you sure the css are loaded in the correct order? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#callout-navbar-fixed-top-padding

Comment: Yes I have followed the docs but when I try to do the padding top it will give me a big blank space so I had used this 2 solution based on the questions that I found, margin:0px and also @media(max-width). And also when I try to put it in the body of my content it still blocks their content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the "padding-top: 60px;" style to whatever element is wrapping the "@yield('content')" area rather than to the body element. Hopefully, that will push your content below the absolute-positioned navigation bar.

Comment: You mean something like <div style="padding-top:60px">@yield('content')</div>

Comment: Oh yup this work, I guess I was too focused on the body tag that I forgot that the main important thing is in the @yield ('content ') part. Thank you so much for your help :)