# add some margin or padding to show the section under sticky navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using `scroll-behavior: smooth` css for smooth scrolling. The navigation bar is sticky and when a click on the menu item it take me to the defined section.

The problem is the section goes under the sticky navbar. I want it to stop till the height of navbar.

I am using bootstrap 4+.

I have not use any java scripts. So how can I give some margin or padding to the section?

Comment: show us some code

Answer (score 0):

[top nav bar blocking top content of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336194/top-nav-bar-blocking-top-content-of-the-page)

Add to your CSS:

```
body { 
    padding-top: 65px; 
}
```

From the Bootstrap docs:

The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body.

Comment: The navbar is transparent and when scroll happen it changes the background color. So if I give padding to top it will have white blank space.

Comment: Add the padding to the content container, if you share your page or your code it will be easier to help.